# "Failed to instantiate one or more class" error in XML, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button1"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="@string/button2"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="@string/button3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.bottomsheettest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.1"
}
```

In the XML preview, there is an error that says:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGPU2.png)

Which is strange because it is a NullPointerException Error.
I have not updated anything in the Main activity file.

I plan on adding a bottom sheet to this which is why I added the Coordinate Layout tag. Ever since I added that tag, I cannot find any way to remove this error.

Comment: You don't have an AppCompatTextView here

Answer (score 2):

The error was resolved after I removed the lintOptions and allProject components, and replaced the dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about the `26.0.1` just downgrade it to `26.0.0` it's more stable. don't forget to downgrade all the android libs too

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this error:

**"android...Coordinator Layout" and "Failed to instantiate one or more classes"**

I tried these many **"failed"** attempts:

> 1. Changing API level in design tab of an XML file.
> 2. Changing design theme
> 3. Installing newest SDK files etc.

But finally after few sleepless night, I was able to do it by:

> 1. Un-installing the complete Android Studio and SDK downloaded files. [NOTE: this also helped me in saving precious space in my 120GB MAC
>      book]
> 2. Installing default SDK files as prompted during installation.
> 3. Changing a little in my **"build.gradle"** file. "Compiles SDK version", "target SDK version" and "dependencies" all have the same
>      level. [26 in my case; my min SDK was 15]

And this again given me an error after syncing Gradle.
But It showed some error [something with MAVEN kind of forgotten to take the snapshot of that error] and I just downloaded that extra file required for the same.

And then, IT WORKED.

Comment: nor Edit: "And this again given me error after syncing gradle. But It showed some error [something with MAVEN...kind of forgotten to take the snapshot of that error] and I just downloaded that extra file required for the same." After checking my error log, its something related to " *daemon not started". I started it by the link suggested in the error log and things became smooth.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Fritsch for editing my answer and making it better.

Actually, just now I leaned the use of "shift+return" to go to next line in the comment section of Stackoverflow. [in Mac].